# How to handle MySQL strict mode and TEXT Columns on INSERT?

Tags: mysql, insert, default

In MySQL 5.7 the default SQL mode contains STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. If a INSERT query does not contain all columns, those missing columns need a default value, otherwise MySQL will throw an Error.
But TEXT columns do not allow any Default Value so how are we supposed to work with this behaviour?

Example:

```
Create table test1 (
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  some_comment text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test1 (name) VALUES ('test');
```

The INSERT will throw an error

```
#1364 - Field 'some_comment' doesn't have a default value
```

As i can not asign a default value to a TEXT column i see few choices:

1. Each INSERT query has to address all columns and a default is never needed, but i dont see where this is elegant or usefull.
2. Don't use TEXT - but thats no Option for really long strings or big tables due to the row size limit.
3. Use INSERT IGNORE at least for all tables containing TEXT columns - this affects all columns in the INSERT and seems like a dirty workaround.
4. Don't use strict mode - why is it default when i cant use it?
5. Make all Text Columns nullable, but in most cases Char/Varchar Columns are defined with Default '' and therefore it would not be consistant. (thx to comments)

Which solution am i missing here?

Edit: As i don't see a better way i am going with #5 for now.

Comment: A column is defined `not null` to enfore the integrity of a data model. If you want to be able to add values into a table without making sure they have a meaning according to the data model: why not just define it as nullable? That would be, by the way, your missing 5th solution.

Comment: I am not sure how mysql handles this but in lot of databases NOT NULL is more performant than a nullable column as the check if a column is NULL or has data is additional work. An empty string is a perfectly fine default for a comment. Making TEXT columns nullable would be a solution but it would (in most cases) not be consistent with the usage of varchar types and so on.

Comment: `NULL` does not mean `''`

Comment: Of course not. But that is not the point.

Comment: I am not sure what your goal here is. You want to optimize your database at the wrong place because of some ominous performance reason you heard about `null`, while you might break your datamodel. The reason people use `default = ''` is that they actually want to treat `null` values as `''` (what is a fair assumption for strings) and don't want to use stuff like `where ifnull(some_comment, '') = ''` all the time. If you want to have a not null text column with a default value, use `varchar(65535) not null default ''`. If you want to optimize, use indexes, not `null`-magic.

Comment: It is not only about performance - i am a friend of only using `NULL` if it clearly makes sense or is neccessary. Foreign Keys, datetime columns and so on - but in 99% of other columns there is no use in distinguishing `NULL` and `0` or `NULL` and `''`, furthermore MySQL queries like `WHERE x != 'whatever' or x IS NULL` are a pain. You can not always use varchar, especially if a table has some more text fields you reach the size limit really soon.

Comment: I am going with Solution #5 as i want to make the software strict mode friendly but i still dont like it and its gonna be a real pain to look for queries which possibly could need a change in a project with hundreds of tables...